# Tkinter: How to return a parameter after clicking a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I return a parameter after using a button in tkinter?

```py
def read(excelfile):
    data = pd.ExcelFile("rsc/" + excelfile + ".xlsx")
    file = pd.read_excel(data)
    return file

browse_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=lambda:read(), bg="#20bebe", fg="white", width=15, height=2)
```

It won't keep working in the function `def read()`.

Comment: There is no point in returning from a button `command`. You can use global variables to pass the result to your main code

Comment: Or better append that variables to a list so that You don't have to use global variables (because they are not good and a bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: @Matiiss First of all the list will be a global variable second of all global variables aren't bad practise if you are using functional programming.

Comment: `read()` does return `file` but it is discarded if the function is used as `command` option directly.  If you use `lambda: print(read())`, you should see something in the console.